# saving dropdown list value in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, adminlte

I need assistance please.

**The scenario:**
I have a table called users and transactions in laravel. Created a blade for transaction table which will pull data as user id drop down list from users table. All user id of users table are show in transaction with dropdown lists. Transaction table has amount column with debit/credit options. User table has total amount column.

**My controller:**

```
DB::table('users')->where('userid', $request->userid)->increment('amount', $request->amount);
```

and
DB::table('users')->where('userid', $request->userid)->decrement('amount', $request->amount);

**What I want to achieve:**

Currently, the dropdown list is working and save data in transaction table but amount can’t be debited or credited in total amount in user tables.

`$request->userid` is not getting value from dropdown list.

Please how do I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your relevant blade code for the dropdown minimally. In the current content it is difficult answer your problem?

Answer (score 0):

### My blade --

```
            <select class="form-control select2 {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email_id" id="email_id" required>
                @foreach($emails as $id => $email)
                    <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('email_id') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $email }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            @if($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
            @endif
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.email_helper') }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="amount">{{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.amount') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('amount') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="number" name="amount" id="amount" value="{{ old('amount', '') }}"        step="1">
            @if($errors->has('amount'))
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('amount') }}</span>
            @endif
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.transaction.fields.amount_helper') }}</span>
       </div>
```

### My controller --

```
{

        DB::table('users')->where('email', $request->email_id)->increment('whatsapp', $request->credits); 
        $transaction = Transaction::create($request->all());
        
       return redirect()->route('admin.transactions.index');
    
}
```

Comment: Edit your question please. This is to answer questions. You added content in the wrong place.